# How to view & copy hidden files & folders in Linux

Tags: linux

Would need some help on viewing & Moving the Hidden Files & Folders.

Comment: Do you want to perform these actions from a command line or within a specific application?

Comment: A little more detail?  Moving a single file or en-masse?

Answer (score 8):

Hidden files are just files with a `.` in the beginning of their name.

To list files, including hidden ones from a command line:

```
ls -a
```

To list *only* hidden files:

```
ls -a .*
```

Hidden files can be moved/copied/removed just like any other file:

```
mv .log .log_old # move a file
cp .log .log_backup # copy a file
rm .log # remove a file
```

Comment: `.*` matches `.` and `..`, so you could get quite a few extra entries.

Comment: @Ignacio: What is the proper way to show only hidden files and not `.` and `..`?

Comment: You have to use `.[^.]*` and `..?*`. Setting the `nullglob` shell option may be helpful to suppress error messages if no files match one of the patterns.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Gnome and the Nautilus file manager, you can select "Show Hidden Files" in the "View" menu. The keyboard shortcut is Ctrl-H.

On the command line the option to "ls" is "-a" to see hidden files (the ones with '.' as the first character in the filename).

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Trey's answer, if you want to copy everything in a given directory, including the hidden files, you should be fine with:

```
  cp -r /something/ /somenewplace/
```

Comment: This command does NOT copy hidden files.